# Durandal knockout click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, durandal

I need your help. I have tried it, but can't find a solution. The clickevent didn't start, when i press the icon, to delete one of the free Days. The other clickevent works. Here my code:

periods.js

```
define(function (require) {
        var backend = require('backend');
        var ko = require('knockout');
        var app = require('durandal/app');

        return {
            active_periods:ko.observableArray([]),
            activate:function(){
                var that = this;
                backend.getActivePeriods().then(function(results){
                    that.active_periods(results);
                });
            },
            editActivePeriod:function(period){
                period.viewUrl = 'views/editActivePeriod';
                app.showDialog(period);
            },
            editFreeDays:function(){
                alert("hh");
            },
            deleteFreeDays:function(){
                alert("ha");
                return app.showMessage('Willst du wirklich diese freien Tag(e) löschen?', '', [ { text: "Ja", value: "Yes" }, { text: "Nein", value: "No" }]);
            }
        };
    });
```

periods.html

```
<section>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3 class="center-block">aktive Perioden</h3>
      <hr>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> neue Periode erstellen</button>
      <br>
      <!-- ko foreach: active_periods -->
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">
                  <!--ko text: name--><!--/ko--> (<!--ko text: startDate--><!--/ko--> - <!--ko text: endDate--><!--/ko-->)<i class="fa fa-cog fa-lg pull-right" data-bind="click:$parent.editActivePeriod"></i>
              </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
              <ul data-bind="foreach: freeDays">
                  <li>
                    <!--ko text: name--><!--/ko-->
                    <i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-lg pull-right" data-bind="click:$parent.deleteFreeDays"></i>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /ko -->
      </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3>archivierte Perioden</h3>
      <hr>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have to disagree with Wayne.  You should instead use the following: `data-bind="click: $root.deleteFreeDays"`.  With this approach, your access to the viewModel won't be structurally dependent.

This is what `$root` is for.

Answer (score 1):

Because freeDays is a child of active_periods which is a child of the view model you need to get the grandparent instead of the parent `data-bind="click: $parents[1].deleteFreeDays"`